# Java, seemingly randomly, started crashing on FileHandle.class.getResourceAsStream(path);

Tags: java, eclipse, file, inputstream

So, I'm working on a program that allows you to import animations in the form of JSON files into Minecraft, and, when working on a completely different part of the program, my import code stopped working.

I'm using eclipse, and this is how my import code looks:

```
package com.github.sam54123.mc_animation.utils;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class FileHandle 
{
    public static InputStream inputStreamFromFile(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = FileHandle.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            return inputStream;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

**new file**

```
package com.github.sam54123.mc_animation.utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONUtils 
{
    public static String getJSONStringFromFile(String path)
    {
        // Open file
        Scanner scanner;
        try 
        {
            InputStream in = FileHandle.inputStreamFromFile(path);
            scanner = new Scanner(in);
            // Get JSON as string without spaces or newlines
            String json = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            // Close file
            scanner.close();

            return json;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }


    }

    public static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromFile(String path)
    {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Path");
            return null;
        }

        String string = getJSONStringFromFile(path);
        return new JSONObject(string);

    }



}
```

And I proceed to do some more fancy pampering of the file later on. This used to work reliably, until I made this in a completely different and un-related class:

```
String command = getCommand(object);

if (command != null && command.length() > 0)
{
    commands.add(new AnimCommand(command, i));
}
```

And then it started throwing this error:

```
   [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7852e922
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:94)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:406)
    at com.github.sam54123.mc_animation.utils.JSONUtils.getJSONObjectFromFile(JSONUtils.java:47)
    at com.github.sam54123.mc_animation.system.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:20)
    at com.github.sam54123.mc_animation.testing.Tester.main(Tester.java:13)
```

I've double checked that the file hasn't changed, and I tried deleting that section of code, restarting Eclipse, the whole deal, and nothing seems to fix it. The code is even able to recognize that the file is valid using the File class, but nothing seems to change. Does anyone have some insight on how this might be fixed? Here is the rest of my code: https://github.com/Sam54123/mc-animation/

**EDIT**

Okay, I've just done some more debugging, and it looks like it's the

```
return new JSONObject(string);
```

on line 47 of the second file that's crashing. No idea why, as the risky stuff of reading a file off disk is okay.

**EDIT 2**
It looks looks like it's failing because

```
InputStream in = FileHandle.inputStreamFromFile(path);
```

is returning null, which makes sense because of the try catch statement

```
InputStream inputStream = FileHandle.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

is in. Why that's failing beats me though, because the validity of the file is verified elsewhere in the code. It also used to work, and I haven't changed anything about the layout of the files.

**EDIT 3**
Interesting, a couple System.out.printlns reveal the catch is not actually getting activated, and therefore getResourceAsStream() must actually be returning null. I've confirmed this by printing it out before I return it.

Comment: Can you point out the line number where the NPE is taking place?

Comment: You're calling `getJSONStringFromFile` twice, with the first call's output fed into the second. Is this really what you intended to do? If the first call actually returns JSON, how can you read it as a file?

Comment: saw that and fixed. That was a debugging step I attempted to take and failed though. Bug still exists.

Comment: Is `string` null?

Comment: Just looked and put it in Edit 2, with a batch of new info

Comment: Please clean up your question and edit it to specify the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: You're confusing files, which can be (and must be) anywhere on the file system, and whose path is a file path relative to the current directory or an absolute file path, and should be read using a FileInputStream, with resources, which must be on the classpath of your Java program, are loaded by the classloader, and are identified by a path relative to the Class on which you call getResourceAsStream(), or must be an absolute path starting at the root of the classpath. If you want to read a file, use file IO. If you want to  load a resource from the classpath, use getResourceAsStream().

Comment: And of cource, the problem is way harder to diagnose as it should be, because instead of throwing an exception where a problem occurs, you catch it, ignore it, and return null instead, which of course leads to more obscure problems later.

Comment: The weird thing is, (sorry for the late reply), I've verified I'm opening the file successfully. If I point it to a non-existent file, it just prints "invalid file" and returns, which is verified working.